# How to Use NextAuth for flutter

Tags: flutter, next.js, next-auth

I want to use my api routes and NextAuthJs as an Authentication for flutter.

I'm building a flutter app and I want to login using NextJs through Standard Flow (Auth code) inside web page. I opted for next-auth. I configured it for `username/password` using a MySQL database. I can login using next-auth.

How can I use that to login inside my flutter app? I literally didn’t find anything!